# Git hook to check presence of code

Tags: git, githooks

I have limited knowledge in git to understand the documentation on `git-hooks`. I wanted to know if there is a way to add a `git-hook` or some other construct such that it can check whether some code is present/commented out in one of the files. My workflow is that I have a configuration file `globalConfig.js` which contains two set of configurations `development` and `production`. When I am developing, I uncomment out the `development` configuration and comment out `production` configuration but when I commit any code to my repo, I want to make sure that the `production` configuration is uncommented and `development` configuration is commented.

**Excerpt from globalConfig.js file**

**Development**

```
  // Production config - Always uncomment it before commiting
  // const firebaseConfig = {
  //   apiKey: "prod",
  //   authDomain: "prod",
  //   databaseURL: "prod",
  //   storageBucket: "prod",
  //   messagingSenderId: "prod"
  // };

  // Dev config - Always comment out before commiting
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "dev",
    authDomain: "dev",
    databaseURL: "dev",
    storageBucket: "dev",
    messagingSenderId: "dev"
  };
```

**Production**

```
  // Production config - Always uncomment it before commiting
  const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "prod",
   authDomain: "prod",
   databaseURL: "prod",
   storageBucket: "prod",
   messagingSenderId: "prod"
  };

  // Dev config - Always comment out before commiting
  // const firebaseConfig = {
  //  apiKey: "dev",
  //  authDomain: "dev",
  //  databaseURL: "dev",
  //  storageBucket: "dev",
  //  messagingSenderId: "dev"
  //};
```

Is it possible to achieve it via `git-hook`or some other git construct?

Comment: This should be possible, but for a more accurate answer it would be good to see snippets of the `globalConfig.js` with the production and development configuration since the pre-commit hook is going to do a bunch of `grep`ing to validate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pre-commit hook should get you started. If a file has the word `development` in it then it must be a comment otherwise the commit is not allowed.

Steps:

1. Create `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with the following content:

```
    git diff --cached --name-status | while read file; 
    do
                if egrep "development" $file ; then
                    echo "ERROR: Disallowed development configuration in file: ${file}"
                    exit 1
                fi
    done || exit $?
```

Note that the egrep expression is very simple atm, but you should be able to modify it according to your requirements (i.e the exact content of `globalConfig.js`) OR, you can update your questions with snippets from `globalConfig.js` :)

2. Change permissions

`chmod 755 .git/hooks/pre-commit`

3. And then try committing an invalid `globalConfig.js` file. Here is what my test showed:

```
☻  cat globalConfig.js                                 SomeOtherFeature/abc 0d174e2 ✗
//Configuration
var Production = new String("Production Configuration");
var development = new String("development Configuration");

$ git add globalConfig.js

$ git commit -m "Commit should not be allowed"
Checking if globalConfig.js is valid
var development = new String("development Configuration");
ERROR: Disallowed development configuration in file: globalConfig.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and sorry for my delay in responding. I have updated the questions with the excerpts of `globalConfig.js` file that I need to check before committing. I have a couple of questions:1. Is the `pre-commit` script running against all the files that are being committed or can I run it against some specific files only? 2. I am not sure which scripting language is used to write the actual script but is that only language we can write the pre-commit hook or can I also use some other language such as Python.

Comment: 1. If you change `git diff --cached --name-status` to `git diff --cached --name-status -- globalConfig.js` that is what the hook will run against. 2. You can write the hook in python. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311869/writing-git-hooks-in-python-bash-scripts).

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. I will give the python script a try.